# A question about probability (WLLN)

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series

$X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ are i.i.d r.v.$P(X_n=-1)=p_0,P(X_n=2^k-1)=p_k, k\in N. $where      $p_0=1-\sum\limits_k p_k,p_k=\frac{1}{2^kk(k+1)}.$ How to prove
\begin{equation}
\frac{S_n}{\frac{n}{\log_2n}}\xrightarrow{P} -1.
\end{equation}
 where $S_n=X_1+\dots+X_n$

I want to use WLLN to find the similar form and

$EX_n=-p_0+\sum\limits_k\frac{2^k-1}{2^kk(k+1)}=-1+\sum\limits_k\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=0.$

By the Khinchin's law :$\frac{S_n}{n}\xrightarrow{P} 0$. But I don't know how to get its rate.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this come from Resnick's text?

Comment: @Sean Roberson No,it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the similar question from Durrett's book, and I just post the answer by Durrett.

This is question.
[image]

And theorem 2.2.6

[image]
This is the answer by Durrett.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Another similar example in book is:
[image]
[image]
[image]